# How to combine ActiveRecord queries with or

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using the PublicActivity gem and would like to combine two "where" queries with OR. Each query works separately:

```
@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.where(owner_id: current_user.friend_ids, owner_type: "User")

@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.where(recipient_id: current_user.id, recipient_type: "User")
```

The goal is:

return the activities where owner_id is current_user.friend_ids **OR** recipient_id is current_user.id. I tried this but it didn't work:

```
@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.where("owner_id LIKE ? OR recipient_id LIKE ?', current_user.friend_ids, current_user.id)
```

I already tried the squeel gem and also where(...).or.where(...)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `current_user.friend_ids` returning an array of values? If so I believe you want to use `IN` instead of `LIKE`, such as `owner_id IN (?)`. Also, you said "I tried this but it didn't work"; can you describe what didn't work? Did you get an error? were incorrect results returned? Were no results returned? etc

Comment: check https://github.com/oelmekki/activerecord_any_of

Comment: @Teeg yes, friend_ids is returning an array of values and it's working with owner_id IN (?)! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
where("owner_id IN (?) OR recipient_id IN (?)', current_user.friend_ids, current_user.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

`like OR like` is notorious for the wrong results, false positives, etc.

How about using:

```
@activities1 = PublicActivity::Activity.where(owner_id: current_user.friend_ids, owner_type: "User")

@activities2 = PublicActivity::Activity.where(recipient_id: current_user.id, recipient_type: "User")

@activities=(@activities1+@activities2).sort.unique
```

since or will effectively the distinct of both record sets. (just added .sort.uniq)